# PHP mail reply to sender instead of server email

Tags: php, email, header, mail-sender

Can anyone point out where am I getting this form wrong? Instead of being able to reply to the "**email**" from the sender I get the server email.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: business.com'; 
    $to = 'anyone@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'A new Message from your website business.com';
    $human = $_POST['human'];
    $headers = 'From: info@business.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

and here is the **html**

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" target="contactIframe" name="contact">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea></br>
    <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here"></br></br>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Clear" onclick="this.form.reset();">
</form>
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You mail function is does not have `$headers` as additional headers. The code should be...

```
 if ($human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
       echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    }
 }
```

ref : [PHP Mail Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Wow...you right, I have missed the, however, there is still somewhere to edit as the addition to the $headers is now triggering the echo error message

Comment: Check is you have `$body` defined in the code... if it is there, then check for server `error_log`.

Comment: Hey Gopakumar, thanks for helping here, the  $body tag is in the code as you can see above, I am not sure I can access the server error log though.